# How do I add line breaks e.g. \\n in a Apache POI HWPF Document

Tags: java, apache-poi, transformation, doc, hwpf

I have to modify Word Document in the old .doc format. Using Apache POI with the HWPF representation of the document. I struggled to insert line breaks into any table cell. In the modified document line breaks look like empty boxes.

[table cell with added line break](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hs2Z.png)

The Code I used for this after I selected the specific cell:

```
cell.insertBefore("Test "+System.lineSeparator()+" Test");
```

The Following also doesnt work:

```
cell.insertBefore("Test "+System.getProperty("line.seperator")+" Test"); 
cell.insertBefore("Test \n Test");
cell.insertBefore("Test \r\n Test");
```

everything I tried was transformed into boxes.

I also tried writing the document to a temp file and then just replacing a placeholder with `HWPF -> empty` boxes.Does anybody know a solution to this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Forget about `apache poi` `HWPF`. It is in scratchpad and without any progress since decades. And there are no useable methods to insert or create new paragraphs. All `Range.insertBefore` and `Range.insertAfter` methods which take more than only text are private and deprecated and doesn't work properly also since decades. The reason of that may be that the binary file format of `Microsoft Word` `HWPF` of course is the most horrible file format of all the other horrible file formats like `HSSF`, `HSLF`. So who wants bothering with this?

But to answer your question:

In word processing text is structured in paragraphs containing text runs. Each paragraph takes a new line by default. But "Text\nText" or "Text\rText" or "Text\r\nText" stored in a text run would only mark a line break within that text run but not a new paragraph. Would ..., because of course `Microsoft Word` has it's own rules. There `\u000B` marks that line break within the text run.

So what you could do is the following:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.hwpf.*;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.usermodel.*;

public class ReadAndWriteDOCTable {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  HWPFDocument document = new HWPFDocument(new FileInputStream("TemplateDOC.doc"));

  Range bodyRange = document.getRange();
  System.out.println(bodyRange);
  
  TableIterator tableIterator = new TableIterator(bodyRange);
  while (tableIterator.hasNext()) {
   Table table = tableIterator.next();
   System.out.println(table);
   TableCell cell = table.getRow(0).getCell(0); // first cell in table
   System.out.println(cell);
   Paragraph paragraph = cell.getParagraph(0); // first paragraph in cell
   System.out.println(paragraph); 
   CharacterRun run = paragraph.insertBefore("Test\u000BTest");
   System.out.println(run); 
  }
  
  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("ResultDOC.doc");
  document.write(out);
  out.close();
  document.close();
  
 }
}
```

That places the text run "Test\u000BTest" before first paragraph in first cell of each table in the document. And the `\u000B` marks a line feed within that text run.

Maybe that is what you wanted to achieve? But, as said, forget about `apache poi` `HWPF`. The next unsolvable problem is only a step far away.

Comment: Thank you so much. I would also much rather work with a different file Format. Sadly I don't have any influence over that. Is there a better maintained library instead of apache poi hwpf?

Comment: @MartinCode: "Is there a better maintained library instead of apache poi hwpf?" Except the commercial ones like `Aspose` and Co? Not that I am aware of.

Comment: try docx4j for example

Comment: @GGK: That question was about `HWPF`. This is processing the old binary Word format `*.doc`. How shall docx4j work with that binary format?

Comment: you are right...docx4j is for *.docx...I would suggest XWPFRun run = cells.getParagraphs().get(0).createRun(); and then run.addbreak(); run.setText("Test");